# Rails 3.1.1 excruciatingly slow in development mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, macos, asset-pipeline

EDIT: Disregard everything I wrote about assets. I've disabled them and I'm still having this problem. Running on OSX.

I found an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522781/rails-3-1-is-very-slow-in-development-mode-because-of-assets-what-to-do) that made it sound like it might have to do with assets. Basically I made a virgin app with a form on one page that leads to another and each page TAKES SO SLOW TO LOAD it's driving me crazy.

Here's a snippet from the server log when I make a request:

> Started GET "/assets/pages.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-10
>   22:21:35 -0700 Served asset /pages.css - 304 Not Modified (1ms)
>
> Started GET "/assets/authenticator.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at
>   2012-01-10 22:21:39 -0700 Served asset /authenticator.js - 304 Not
>   Modified (1ms)
>
> Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-10
>   22:21:39 -0700 Served asset /jquery.js - 304 Not Modified (2ms)
>
> Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at
>   2012-01-10 22:21:43 -0700 Served asset /application.js - 200 OK (0ms)
>
> Started GET "/assets/pages.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-10
>   22:21:43 -0700 Served asset /pages.js - 304 Not Modified (1ms)

The loading times the log suggests are not even close to 1-3 seconds per each request.
It is driving me bananas. I installed the plugin as that other answer suggested but I have no idea how to use it or what to write in the settings.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Hope you are using Rails-3.1.Check this link:-http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: Windows? Linux? Mac OS X? More info please.

Comment: OSX. Sorry, forgot to mention.

Comment: Can you show the rest of the log for the given request? Also, what plugin are you referring to?

Comment: Suspect this is down to class reloading in dev mode (`cache_classes` in the config) combined with a non-SSD hard disk. Ruby is pretty bad (read, terrible) when it comes to performance loading files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to look for this line in your `development.log`

```
Completed 200 OK in 476ms (Views: 155.1ms | ActiveRecord: 14.7ms)
```

The usual culprit is partials and classes not being cached in development. Alternatively, you can also try this gem: https://github.com/wavii/rails-dev-tweaks