# How can I speed up Rails development server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on Rails 4.2 & Angular 1.4.8 as the front-end. This is my **development.rb** file:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.eager_load = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :letter_opener_web
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {host: "localhost:3000"}
  config.consider_all_requests_local = false
end
```

I know that by disabling `assets.debug` I can really speed this up, but I need to have my assets refreshed when I refresh the page. I am doing full stack so I can't precompile assets all the time.

I recently started using `guard` with `guard-rails` - do I have any chance ?

Comment: do you wish to speed up loading the app or what?

Comment: The process of reloading actually, after I make a change either on the backend or the front. It takes ~20-30 seconds to full refresh the whole page. I am using Vagrant with ubuntu server 14.04LTS on an SSD drive with 2GB of memory. The site runs very fast on production instead of development.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that compiling all assets every time after file changed.

if you `require` angularjs libs and other libs in to `application.js` try to create a separate file for libraries and application

See also: [Rails 3.1 is very slow in development-mode because of assets, what to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522781/rails-3-1-is-very-slow-in-development-mode-because-of-assets-what-to-do)